# Web Scraping through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, firebug, winhttp

I need to fetch company addresses(cim) from site **http://www.ceginfo.hu/**

Example Company Name: AB-KONTÍR Szolgáltató Bt.

I know how to do it using **WinHttp.WinHttpRequest** object and **FireBug**.

> But I am not able to decide to which URL I should send this request.

When I analyse the request/responses using FireBug, I get the following URL:
http://www.ceginfo.hu/company/search/4221638

4221638 is CompanyID here I think. But in my case I will have company name only and that's what my problem is.

So can anybody please tell me where can I get URL using firebug or any other tool using which I can track the URL **with Company Name as parameter** which I can use in my VBA code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> So can anybody please tell me where can I get URL using firebug or any
>   other tool using which I can track the URL with Company Name as
>   parameter which I can use in my VBA code.

No. Unless there is a publicly available database (I would suggest calling them, if you can) or an API that allows for programmatic access, the only way to arrive at this link slug is by executing the search.

Further, the post slog is not as relevant as you think.  If you search for simply "Kontir", this is the resulting page -- with many results:

http://www.ceginfo.hu/company/search/4222407

You're going to have to automate the "search" -- passing the criteria to the Web Page and executing the button-click and/or HTTPPost, and then parse the result(s).  In the example company name, there is only one result. But it is possible as in my example above, that there may be multiple matches for some queries, and then you will need to have a method of dealing with these, or ignoring them.